# How do I loop through columns and update a third column only on the first unique row

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Macros so please excuse me if this is BASIC. I tried searching but could not find an answer.

- Here is the problem statement :

Column A of the worksheet below Has "Vendor Names" and Column B has "Line level Recommendation" which can have values ranging from Scenario 1 through 5.

All I need is that the macro should loop through the Vendor Names column and read the corresponding scenario values in column B, if a value is found then there should be an ‘X’ mark under the corresponding  Scenario Column.

The main requirement is that these values should come only once against the first record of each vendor and should not repeat.

**The format i need is as follows**

| Vendor Name | Line Level Recommendation | Scenario 1 | Scenario 2 | Scenario 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Accenture | Scenario 1 | X | X | X |
| Accenture | Scenario 2 |  |  |  |
| Accenture | Scenario 3 |  |  |  |
| PLK Labs | Scenario 1 | X |  | X |
| PLK Labs | Scenario 3 |  |  |  |

**Result I am getting with my macro is this**

| Vendor Name | Line Level Recommendation | Scenario 1 | Scenario 2 | Scenario 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Accenture | Scenario 1 | X |  |  |
| Accenture | Scenario 2 |  | X |  |
| Accenture | Scenario 3 |  |  | X |
| PLK Labs | Scenario 1 | X |  |  |
| PLK Labs | Scenario 3 |  |  | X |

Please see below the code i have written to achieve this. I know i am supposed to catch a counter when the Vendor name record changes and then use that as my row value for the update but i dont know how to do that.

```
Sub scenario_finder()
 r = 2
 Do While Cells(r, 1) <> ""
 If Cells(r, 2) = "Scenario 1" Then
 Cells(r, 3) = "X"
 ElseIf Cells(r, 2) = "Scenario 2" Then Cells(r, 4) = "X"
 ElseIf Cells(r, 2) = "Scenario 3" Then Cells(r, 5) = "X"
 ElseIf Cells(r, 2) = "Scenario 4" Then Cells(r, 6) = "X"
 ElseIf Cells(r, 2) = "Scenario 5" Then Cells(r, 7) = "X"
 Else
 Cells(r, 8) = ""
 
 End If
 r = r + 1
 Loop
End Sub
```

Any help with a pseudo code will be greatly appreciated as I haven't worked with VBA before and do not know the syntax very well.

Thanks !

**Added on 8/4/2021
The customer needs the following for analysis - Table 3**

| Vendor Name | Line Level Recommendation | Scenario 1 | Scenario 2 | Scenario 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Accenture | Scenario 1 | X | X | X |
| Accenture | Scenario 2 | X | X | X |
| Accenture | Scenario 3 | X | X | X |
| PLK Labs | Scenario 1 | X |  | X |
| PLK Labs | Scenario 3 | X |  | X |

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable to track the row you want to write to.

Assign that variable first in the loop

Something like

```vb
Sub scenario_finder()
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Dim r as long
    Dim VendorHeaderRow as long 

    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' or whatever sheet you want
    With ws
        r = 2
        VendorHeaderRow = r
        Do While .Cells(r, 1) <> vbNullString 
            If .Cells(r - 1, 1).Value2 <> .Cells(r, 1).Value2 Then
                VendorHeaderRow = r
            End If

            Select Case .Cells(r, 2).Value2
               Case "Scenario 1"
                   .Cells(VendorHeaderRow, 3).Value2 = "X"
               Case "Scenario 2"
                   .Cells(VendorHeaderRow, 4).Value2 = "X"
               Case "Scenario 3"
                   .Cells(VendorHeaderRow, 5).Value2 = "X"
               Case "Scenario 4"
                   .Cells(VendorHeaderRow, 6).Value2 = "X"
               Case "Scenario 5"
                   .Cells(VendorHeaderRow, 7).Value2 = "X"
            End Select
            r = r + 1
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Chris , that worked like a Charm ! - When I showed this to my customer she loved it but has an additional request that I am struggling to figure out (sorry - hope I become an expert soon :-) - Now she wants the result lines not be just against the first new Vendor record but to repeat for ALL the records for the same vendor. I have edited my question and have added a Table 3 at the end to show how it should look like. Perhaps this needs a nested loop on the Columns ? Will this slow down the Macro by a lot if the data set is huge ? Thanks a ton again for your time.

Comment: Re _Will this slow down the Macro by a lot_ yes it will.  Looping over large ranges will always be slow.  A common answer to that is to use a Variant Array approach.  Lots of examples here on SO.

Comment: To achieve the new requirement, keep track of the previous value of VendorHeaderRow, and when it changes, backfill all rows between the old row and the new row - 1.  Since you're getting paid for this and you want to become an expert, I'll leave it to you to figure out the details

Answer (score 0):

### Unique

- It is assumed that there are only two columns (vendors, scenarios). It will write the resulting headers and data next to them.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ScenarioFinder()
    
    ' The Range.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    If rCount = 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Vendor Column
    Dim vcrg As Range: Set vcrg = rg.Columns(1).Resize(rCount - 1).Offset(1)
    Dim vData As Variant: vData = vcrg.Value
    
    ' Scenario Column
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = vcrg.Offset(, 1)
    Dim sArr As Variant: sArr = ArrUniqueColumnRange(scrg)
    Dim sUpper As Long: sUpper = UBound(sArr)
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = scrg.Value
    
    ' Define the Destination Array.
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To sUpper + 1)
    
    Dim rIndex As Long
    Dim cIndex As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    
    ' Write headers.
    For c = 0 To sUpper
        dData(1, c + 1) = sArr(c)
    Next c
    
    ' Write the data.
    For r = 1 To UBound(vData, 1)
        rIndex = Application.Match(vData(r, 1), vcrg, 0) + 1
        cIndex = Application.Match(sData(r, 1), sArr, 0)
        dData(rIndex, cIndex) = "X"
    Next r
    
    ' Create a reference to the Destination Range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = rg.Resize(, UBound(sArr) + 1).Offset(, 2)
    
    ' Write values from the Destination Array to the Destination Range.
    drg.Value = dData
    
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the unique values from a one-column range in an array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function ArrUniqueColumnRange( _
    ColumnRange As Range) _
As Variant
    If ColumnRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    Dim rCount As Long
    
    With ColumnRange.Columns(1)
        rCount = .Rows.Count
        If rCount = 1 Then
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            Data = .Value
        End If
    End With
    
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        Dim Key As Variant
        Dim r As Long
        For r = 1 To rCount
            Key = Data(r, 1)
            If Not IsError(Key) Then
                If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                    .Item(Key) = Empty
                End If
            End If
        Next r
        If .Count = 0 Then Exit Function ' only error values and/or blanks
        ArrUniqueColumnRange = .Keys
    End With

End Function
```